# How can I integrate activiti workflow engine with Vertx?

Tags: apache, workflow, vert.x, activiti, workflow-engine

In our project, **we are using Vertx** and want to **process our request with a workflow engine** because we have different tasks in our request.

I went through **activiti** WFE but found only spring integration example.

How can I integrate it with Vertx?

Comment: use rest API - https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_rest_api

Comment: I used Spring Boot to integrate with Camunda because Vert.x doesn't have any integration with it either. It worked fine, but litle bit sophisticated.